# Base64 strings are different for same file

Tags: ios, swift, base64, ios13

I have one image file "3.png", when convert it into base64 string I'm getting some string value but that value is not matching with actual base64(tried some online conversion tools) string value of that image, but when i tried to decode both images are same.

```
func readFile(fileName: String, fileType: String) -> String?{
  if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: fileType)
  {
    let fm = FileManager()
    let exists = fm.fileExists(atPath: path)
    if(exists){
      //let fileData = NSData(contentsOfFile: fileLocation, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: &error)

      let content = fm.contents(atPath: path)
      //return content?.base64EncodedData()

      let _content = content?.base64EncodedData()
      // print(_content)

      let resultNSString = NSString(data: _content as! Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!
      //  print(resultNSString)
      return resultNSString as String
    }
  }
  return nil
}
```

Comment: What do you get when you use the terminal base64 command. Which output does it match? Online tool or your swift app?

Comment: Also can you pls print the two values you get from online and your file?